# Why is a Microsoft.Net.Http available in NuGet when it breaks projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

According to http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http:
"This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010"

Why is a project that officially doesn't support Visual Studio 2010 available as an update? It wouldn't be a big deal, except that "Update-Package" with no parameters happily destroys projects with this update, just as the "Update All" button does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the update to version 2.2.15 broke my project and I had to

```
uninstall-package Microsoft.Net.Http -force
install-package Microsoft.Net.Http -Version 2.2.13
```

And then to prevent further updates I edited the packages.config file and set the version to the last working version (for me) using the allowedVersions attribute `allowedVersions="[2.2.13)"`.

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.13" targetFramework="net40" allowedVersions="[2.2.13)" />
```

While this doesn't answer the **why** was the update released it will fix and prevent it in future Update-Package executions.